# Convert Octal to Hex in assembly language using emu8086

Tags: assembly, hex, number-formatting, emu8086, octal

I am new at assembly. My task was to convert Octal to Hex and vice versa. I was only able to code Octal to Binary and then Binary to Hex in two different asm files. Now I really want to merge them together so that I can have Octal to Hex conversion.
Here are both codes:

### Octal to Binary

```
.MODEL SMALL

.DATA

    INP DB 0
    MSG_1 DB "ENTER AN OCTAL NUMBER: $"
    MSG_2 DB "BINARY VALUE OF THIS NUMBER: $"
.CODE

MAIN PROC

    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    
    LEA DX,MSG_1
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    
    MOV SI,0
    MOV AH,1
    MOV CX,0
    INPUT: INT 21H
           MOV INP[SI],AL
           INC CX
           INC SI
           CMP AL,13
           JNE INPUT
           
    CALL NEWLINE
    CALL NEWLINE
            
    LEA DX,MSG_2
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H 

    MOV DI,0 
    MOV AH,2
    DEC CX   
    
    OUTPUT: MOV BL,INP[DI]
            CALL CONVERTOCT
            INC DI
            LOOP OUTPUT
    
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H

ENDP

NEWLINE PROC

    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,10
    INT 21H
    MOV DL,13
    INT 21H
    RET

NEWLINE ENDP 

CONVERTOCT PROC 
    
    SUB BL,48
    SHL BL,5 
    
    MOV DH,0
    CONV:
    SHL BL,1
    JC PRINT1
    JMP PRINT0
    
    PRINT0:
    MOV DL,'0'
    INT 21H
    INC DH
    CMP DH,3
    JE EXIT 
    JMP CONV
    
    PRINT1: 
    MOV DL,'1'
    INT 21H
    INC DH
    CMP DH,3
    JE EXIT 
    JMP CONV
    
    EXIT:
    RET
    
     
    
    
CONVERTOCT ENDP

END
```

### Binary to Hex

```
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK 100H

.DATA 

    MSG_1 DB "ENTER BINARY NUMBER: $"
    MSG_2 DB "HEXADECIMAL OF THE NUMBER: $"
    MSG_3 DB "INVALID!  $"

.CODE

MAIN PROC 

    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    
    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV DL,0AH
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX,MSG_1
    INT 21H
    
    XOR BH,BH

    
INPUT: 

       MOV AH,1
       INT 21H
    
       MOV CH,AL
       CMP CH,0DH
       JE PRINT
    
       CMP CH,'0'
       JL EXIT 
    
       CMP CH,'1'
       JG EXIT
    
       AND CH,15
       SHL BH,1
       OR BH,CH
    
       JMP INPUT    

PRINT:
    
    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV DL,0AH
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX,MSG_2
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,2
    CMP BH,9
    JLE NUMBER 
    
    CMP BH,15
    JLE CHARACTER
    
NUMBER:
   
    ADD BH,48
    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,BH
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
    

CHARACTER:

    ADD BH,55
    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,BH
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
     

EXIT:

    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV DL,0AH
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX,MSG_3
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
    MAIN ENDP

END MAIN
```

Comment: Declare a variable `Value: DW 0` for the number. Read one octal digit from user, isolate its low 3 bits,  make `SHL [Value],3`, copy those 3 bits to it, then continue until `0DH` is read.  Now you have the octal number stored in `[Value]`  which you can print in hexadecimal notation.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .DATA
>     INP DB 0
> ```

You might want to correct this error first. Your *INP* input buffer only has room for a single byte! The correct way to write this is `INP db 6 dup (0)`, for 5 octal digits and the carriage return.

### Conversion from Octal to Hex

First pick an available register to act as an accumulator for the octal digits you will input. Choosing the `BP` register allows processing up to 5 octal digits.
Then modify the *CONVERTOCT* proc in the first program to no longer *print* the binary digits, but rather **collect them in this accumulator**.

```
CONVERTOCT PROC
    push cx
    mov  cl, 5      ; 8086 didn't have shift by immediate, and so should emu8086!
    shl  bl, cl     ; The conversion happens for free via this shift left
  CONV:
    shl  bl, 1      ; Out at the top
    rcl  BP, 1      ; In at the bottom
    sub  cl, 2      ; 3 iterations
    jnb  CONV
    pop  cx
    ret
CONVERTOCT ENDP
```

Your second program (that can print Hex), expects its input in `BH`. Either modify that code so it can use the value from the `BP` register, or lower your ambitions to 2 octal digits and convert from `BP` to `BH`:

```
mov  bx, BP
mov  bh, bl
```